# Calling time() multiple times bad?

Tags: php, optimization, timestamp, pagespeed

I was just going through some code and was wondering if it is bad to call *time()* multiple times on a page?

Yes, I know that it will work when called repeatedly, but will there be a big speed difference?

```
Option #1: Call time() whenever you need the current Unix timestamp.

Option #2: Set a variable $timestamp = time(); and call the variable whenever the time is needed.
```

Comment: Measure the difference and see if it matters in your case. There is no objective answer to this question. (Also your two options are _not_ equivalent.)

Comment: @Mat How are they not equivalent?  And one of the answers stated that there would be a speed difference.

Comment: If you use `$timestamp = time();` then use `$timestamp` in a script that runs for say 3 seconds, you'll always print the same time. If you always use `time()`, you'll see different values. This is quite a big difference. Of course there will be a performance difference. Whether it is big or not noticeable depends entirely on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the situation. Some scripts run for more than a few seconds, some could run for hours. Then the new value of time() would be wanted.

If a difference in time that is shorter than the time it takes for your php code to execute won't cause any problems then you might as well use Option #2 since it is **slightly** faster. But, the speed difference is negligible unless you make **tons** of calls to time().

Comment: Calling it about 10 times should not make that much of a difference, right?

Comment: That's right. Calling time() 10 times wouldn't hurt anything. You just might get a one second difference from one call to the next. Just keep in mind that a one second difference can also be a one year difference if it happens during the last second of a year. If that will cause your code to break or have unexpected results than Option 2 would be better.

Comment: Yeah makes sense.  And for logging security stuff one value would be better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'd expect time() to be reasonably cheap, but if you call it multiple times on the same page you could get some unexpected inconsistencies. For example, suppose you call it twice, once to display the date and once to display the time. If the date changes between the two calls, you could end up showing midnight of the previous day, or 23:59:59 of the next day (depending on the order of the calls).

I would normally expect the whole page to be treated as being rendered in a single instant, in terms of any times displayed - so call it once, and use that single value in multiple places.

Comment: If my pages are being generated in 0.06194 seconds, then would I wouldn't really see that difference...correct?

Comment: @Flipper: No, incorrect. Just because it happens quite fast, that doesn't mean you'll never get a different result when you call `time()` twice. The page could still start to be rendered one millisecond (one *microsecond*) before midnight, couldn't it?

Comment: That means that you should expect to see the value change during execution on average every 16 times your script is executed (1/0.06194).

Comment: +1 You make a good point.  And @PaulPRO that is actually big..every 16 times!  I am definitely going to go back and make sure it is only called once.  I had to accept PaulPRO's answer because he also answered my speed question.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the fact if time() makes a kernel call necessary or not? If it is (and I'd assume it were?) than the overhead would be quite large.

Comment: @Voo: Large compared with the rest of the costs of servicing an HTTP response? I suspect not. Overhead is always relative.